# Can anyone help me understand this piece of code?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

Can anyone please help me understand this code?
This code is used to solve this problem.
You are playing a game on your cellphone. You are given an array of length n, indexed from 0 to n−1. Each element of the array is either 0 or 1. You can only move to an index which contains 0. At first you are at the 0th position. In each move you can do one of the following things:

Walk one step forward or backward.
Make a jump of exactly length m forward.
That means you can move from position x to x+1, x−1 or x+m in one move. The new position must contain 0. Also you can move to any position greater than n-1.

You can't move backward from position 0. If you move to any position greater than n−1, you win the game.

Given the array and the length of the jump, you need to determine if it's possible to win the game or not.

```
        n = sc.nextInt();
        m = sc.nextInt();
        field = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            field[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        if (makeMove(0, new LinkedList<Integer>()))
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
```

.
.
.

```
private boolean makeMove(int position, List<Integer> prevPositions) 
  {
  if (prevPositions.contains(position)) 
    return false;
    prevPositions.add(position);

    if (position < 0) return false;
    else if (position >= n) return true;
    else if (field[position] == 1) return false;
    else {
        return makeMove(position + m, prevPositions) ||
                makeMove(position + 1, prevPositions) ||
                makeMove(position - 1, prevPositions);
    }
}
```

input: 6 2

```
   0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Output: Yes

input: 6 2

```
   0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Output: No

Comment: Why dont you ask the person which let you copy homework ?

Comment: Code looks pretty self-explanatory to me, though it's not that well written/formatted, and I'd have used a `Set` instead of a `List`. It uses recursive calls for backtracking invalid moves.

Comment: @John Sorry dude. Not its not a homework. Was practicing on Hacker rank. My code was messy and couldn't pass all test cases so I was going through the submissions there I came cross this code. [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-1d-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I am assuming that you understand the concept of recursion, which is calling a method within itself, if not you may want to look it up.

The first section of code is very simple. It initializes the move length `m` and the array of length `n` and populates it with random binary digits.

The `makeMove` method goes through a few base cases to see if a branch of recursion has failed or succeeded.

1.) `if (prevPositions.contains(position)) 
    return false;
    prevPositions.add(position);`

After making a move, this code checks whether you have already gotten to this position. If you have, it returns `false` because this case has already been known to be false, otherwise the method would have already returned `true`.

2.)  `if (position < 0) return false;
    else if (position >= n) return true;
    else if (field[position] == 1) return false;`

-You can't have a negative position, so that returns `false`.
-If your position is greater than `n` then you win, so return `true`
-You can't move to a position that contains a non-zero digit, so return `false`

3.) `return makeMove(position + m, prevPositions) ||
                makeMove(position + 1, prevPositions) ||
                makeMove(position - 1, prevPositions);`

This code makes recursive calls to other moves from possible positions and returns `true` if any of these calls are true. Since you can leap to `position+m`, then it makes sense that if `makeMove(position+m, prevPositions)` is true, then `makeMove(position, prevPositions)` is also true. Similarly you can move to `position+1` and `position-1` so calls to `makeMove` of these positions should return the same value as `makeMove` of your original position. Hope this made sense!

Comment: Thanks @stanfordude . :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine. Please try this. you need to pass, the element array length  and the jump values.

```
public static boolean decideMove(int[] elements, int length, int jump){
    boolean result = false;
    boolean makeMove = true;
    int currentPosition = 0;
        while(makeMove){
            if (currentPosition + jump > length-1){
                return true;
            } 

            if(elements [currentPosition + jump] == 0){
                currentPosition = currentPosition + jump;
                if (currentPosition + jump > length-1){
                    return true;
                } 
            }
            if (elements[currentPosition + 1] == 0){
                currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                if (currentPosition + jump > length-1){
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            if(elements[currentPosition +1] ==1 && elements[currentPosition + jump]==1){
                if(elements[currentPosition - 1]==0){
                    currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
                } else{
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

    return result;
}
```